# Checking if the event is triggered by the window in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, window

Is there a way to check if an event was triggerd by the 'window'?

I tried the following but window does not have a method called isSameNode():

```
if(window.isSameNode(ev.srcElement)){
    alert();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use this?

```
if(e.srcElement === window)
```

That seems to work in webkit console just fine when I resize the window after running

```
$(window).resize(function(e){ console.log( e.srcElement === window) }); // returns true
```